# Efficient way to test a symmetric function on all pairings of a Seq

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a collection like `[ "a"; "b"; "c" ]` and I want to test every element against every *other* element.

I could generate all pairs like this:

```ml
let combinations xs = 
  Seq.allPairs xs xs 
  |> Seq.filter (fun (x, y) -> x <> y) 
  |> Seq.toList

combinations [ "a"; "b"; "c" ] 
// [("a", "b"); ("a", "c"); ("b", "a"); ("b", "c"); ("c", "a"); ("c", "b")]
```

But for my test, I always know that `f x y = f y x` (since `f` is symmetric), so I want to trim the number of combinations tested:

```ml
let combinations xs = 
  Seq.allPairs xs xs 
  |> Seq.filter (fun (x, y) -> x <> y && x < y) 
  |> Seq.toList

combinations [ "a"; "b"; "c" ] 
// [("a", "b"); ("a", "c"); ("b", "c")]
```

But this:

1. Doesn't seem like an efficient way to generate the test cases
2. Requires that `x : comparison`, which I don't think should be necessary

How should I implement this in F#?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about efficient - this looks like you need to cache the pairs already generated and filter on their presence in the cache.

The library implementation of `Seq.allPairs` goes along these lines:

```
let allPairs source1 source2 =
    source1 |> Seq.collect (fun x -> source2 |> Seq.map (fun y -> x, y))
// val allPairs : source1:seq<'a> -> source2:seq<'b> -> seq<'a * 'b>
```

Then you integrate the caching and filtering into this, constraining both sequences to type `seq<'a>` and introducing the `equality` constraint.

```
let allPairs1 source1 source2 =
    let h = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet()
    source1 |> Seq.collect (fun x -> 
        source2 |> Seq.choose (fun y -> 
            if x = y || h.Contains (x, y) || h.Contains (y, x) then None
            else h.Add (x, y) |> ignore; Some (x, y) ) )
// val allPairs1 :
//     source1:seq<'a> -> source2:seq<'a> -> seq<'a * 'a> when 'a : equality
```

Test

```
allPairs1 [1..3] [2..4] |> Seq.toList
// val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); (2, 3); (2, 4); (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that assumes all elements are distinct (it uses position as identity):

```ml
let allSymmetricPairs xs =
  seq {
    let xs = Seq.toArray xs

    for i = 0 to Array.length xs - 2 do
      for j = i + 1 to Array.length xs - 1 do
        yield xs.[i], xs.[j]
  }
```

We can also pre-allocate the array, which may be faster if you plan to pull the whole sequence:

```
let allSymmetricPairs xs =
  let xs = Seq.toArray xs
  let n = Array.length xs

  let result = Array.zeroCreate (n * (n - 1) / 2)

  let mutable k = 0

  for i = 0 to n - 2 do
    for j = i + 1 to n - 1 do
      result.[k] <- xs.[i], xs.[j]
      k <- k + 1

  result
```

Answer (score 1):

Because *f* is commutative, the simplest way to get all combinations is to project each item into a pair with the remainder of the list.

```
let rec combinations = function
| [] -> []
| x::xs -> (xs |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y))) @ (combinations xs)
```

We don't need any comparison constraint.

```
let xs = [1; 2; 3; 4;]
combinations xs // [(1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); (2, 3); (2, 4); (3, 4)]
```

Checking the results with @kaefer's method:

```
combinations xs = (allPairs1 xs xs |> Seq.toList) // true
```